# In-App purchase that activates after some time

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

I need to implement an In-App Purchase feature on an app that will run on both iOS and Android, I'm not sure if the task I'm trying to accomplish is allowed so I'm asking here for help.

Basically the client asked me to create an app that will be free on the store but limited by an utilization count.
There is an audio player inside the app and the client wants to let the user play the audio files a maximum of 3 times and then lock the app, the user will then need to make an in-app purchase to unlock the app forever.

Now the problem is, the client wants this to be "activated" after a couple of months since the app's launch, so for the first 2 months the app will be free for everyone without any restriction and then the in-app purchase will kick in. New users will pay after 3 "play" but already registered users should not pay and keep using the app for free forever.

Can it be implemented or it's against apple or google policies?

Comment: Well, I'm going to submit an app with similar IAP features in the next few days (some features are limited until you pay, payment is activated from a backend trigger)... I'll post the result here once I get a feedback from Apple.